# Robot class - Java

Tags: java, awtrobot

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public final class test
{
    private static Robot robot;
    public static boolean clickStatus;

    public static void leftClick (int R, int G, int B)
    {
            Color myColorToMatch = new Color (R, G, B);
            BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture (new Rectangle (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenSize ()));
            int w = image.getWidth (null);
            int h = image.getHeight (null);
            int[] rgbs = new int[w*h];
            image.getRGB (0, 0, w, h, rgbs, 0, w);
            for (int y=0; y<h; y++) {
                for (int x=0; x<w; x++) {
                      if (new Color (image.getRGB (x, y)).equals (myColorToMatch))
                               robot.mouseMove(x, y);
                               robot.mousePress (InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                               robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                               break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            try
            {
                    robot = new Robot();
            }
            catch(Exception Error)
            {
                    Error.printStackTrace();
            }             
            // dImp: 130,40,32 - 160,99,57 - 217,135,79
            // banker: 139, 130, 129                
            boolean botLoop = true;
            boolean bankStatus;

            while (botLoop == true)
            {
                    robot.delay (1000);
                    leftClick (96,96,98);
            }
    }
}
```

But there's a problem and I don't know how to fix it. The bot will just Keep clicking every second where ever the mouse is and not go over to/click the desired pixel.
Could someone please help me with this? I can't find the error

Comment: What is the unconditional "break" next to the inner for loop for?

Comment: To end the for loop. If I don't add that, it will just keep clicking. it goes through my screen's size 1600x900

Comment: but the outer for loop will only run for y = 0 and then break. Right? and the inner if block only is one line with no curly brace

Comment: `while (botLoop == true)` is, btw. equivalent to `while (botLoop)` and to `while (((botLoop == true) == true) == true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have brackets around the mousePress and Release so regardless of the color it still presses the mouse, and some other issues...

```
 import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public final class fff {
    private static Robot robot;
    public static boolean clickStatus;

    public static void leftClick(int R, int G, int B) {
        Color myColorToMatch = new Color(R, G, B);
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        int w = image.getWidth(null);
        int h = image.getHeight(null);
        int[] rgbs = new int[w * h];
        image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, rgbs, 0, w);
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                if (new Color(image.getRGB(x, y)).equals(myColorToMatch)) {
                    robot.mouseMove(x, y);
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (Exception Error) {
            Error.printStackTrace();
        }
        // dImp: 130,40,32 - 160,99,57 - 217,135,79
        // banker: 139, 130, 129
        boolean botLoop = true;
        while (botLoop == true) {
            robot.delay(1000);
            leftClick(0, 0, 0);
            break; //no lop
        }
    }
}
```